# QTP - How to check if a collection of object is empty

Tags: if-statement, null, qtp, hp-uft

I'm facing a little problem: I'm trying to understand if a collection of object is empty or not. 
Basically I'm making a connection with a DB and launching a simple SELECT query: if there are no results then I want to stop the execution of the test... 
This is the part of the code interested:

```
    If ctrl(0).value = 0  Then
        reporter.ReportEvent 1, "Process stopped", 
        "The operation has failed"
    End If
```

Obviously if the query returns no value then ctrl(0) does not exist and QTP stops the execution telling me that either it corresponds to the beginning or the end of the object... 
How can I solve it?!

Edit: if I count the objects in the collection, it returns 6. This is the number of columns that the entity in the DB has. But every column is empty so the SELECT does not return a value...

Comment: If you don´t show the code that creates the ctrl identifier, we cannot know what´s wrong/improvable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whether the Recordset is EOF .Please check the code below

```
If not objRecordSet.EOF then
            StrValue=objRecordSet(0)
            Else
            ExitTest
End IF
```

Comment: how you are connecting to DB . VBscript does .QTP use vbscripting . You can achieve it through that

Comment: I create an adodb.connection object

Comment: Then it should work .EOF and BOF are properties of recordset .